# I am working on a databricks notebook running with ADLSV2 using service principle id but receive the following error after mounting my drive

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-databricks, service-principal

I am working on a databricks notebook running with ADLSV2 using service 
    priciple id but receive the following error after mounting my drive.

```
StatusCode=403

StatusDescription=This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.


    configs = {"dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type": 
    "ClientCredential",
    "dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id": "78jkj56-2ght-2345-3453-b497jhgj7587",
    "dfs.adls.oauth2.credential": dbutils.secrets.get(scope = 
    "DBRScope", key = "AKVsecret"),
    "dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url": 
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/bdef8a20-aaac-4f80-b3a0- 
    d9a32f99fd33/oauth2/token"}

    dbutils.fs.mount(source = 
    "adl://<accountname>.azuredatalakestore.net/tempfile",mount_point = 
    "/mnt/tempfile",extra_configs = configs)


    %fs ls mnt/tempfile
```

Comment: You may refer end-to-end walkthrough the steps, and hopefully with this you can get everything working just perfectl
Refer: https://deep.data.blog/2019/03/28/avoiding-error-403-request-not-authorized-when-accessing-adls-gen-2-from-azure-databricks-while-using-a-service-principal/

Answer (score 0):

The uri for your lake is a gen1 uri not gen2. Either way your service principal does not have permission to access the lake. As a test make it a resource owner, then remove it and work out what permissions are missing.